# Azure Devops: Deleted users are being suggested when assigning tasks in boards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-boards

We deleted about 15 users in an organizations in Azure Devops but their names are still being show in the "assign to" dropdown in azure boards. This is causing confussion and errors because you can't assign a task or PBI to a deleted user.

We already check Azure Entra, AD, Office 365 admin, etc and in everywhere the users are deleted and they not appear. They are just being shown in the asign to dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Recently assigned users will be displayed in the dropdown list even though they have been deleted. To resolve this, you can refer to the following steps.

1. Select the deleted user from the dropdown list. You will see the following error since there is no such user in the org and AAD:
   [image]
2. Close the work item and go to any other page. Refresh the page. Go to the work item again. Then check if the deleted user is displayed in the dropdown list.
3. If you still can see the deleted users, clear the browser caches and try again.